# In Swift, is there a way of determining whether an enum is based on a certain type (eg. String)?

Tags: swift, enums

In order to write generic code for an NSValueTransformer, I need to be able to check that an enum is of type String for example. Ie.:

```
enum TestEnum: String {
  case Tall
  case Short
}
```

I am expecially interested in a test that can be used with the guard statement. Something allong the line of:

```
guard let e = myEnum as <string based enum test> else {
  // throw an error
}
```

Please note that not all enums have raw values. For eample:

```
enum Test2Enum {
  case Fat
  case Slim
}
```

Hence a check on the raw value type can not be used alone for this purpose.

**EDIT**

After some further investigation it has become clear that NSValueTransformer can not be used to transform Swift enums. Please see my second comment from matt's answer.

Comment: Take the raw value of any case and see what type it is.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but not all enums have raw types. Eg. enum Test2Enum { ... }. Because it does not "inherit" form a type it does not have a raw value.

Comment: But then it cannot be a RawRepresentable, which is easy to find out

Comment: Matt, 'guard let v = value as? RawRepresentable else' seems to fail to compile with this error: "protocol 'RawRepresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements". Any suggestions?

Comment: Your entire premise is so artificial that I don't know what you want a suggestion _for_.

Comment: How are you planning on interacting with an enum where you don't know the type?

Comment: I want to check if a variable of type AnyObject? is an enum and if the enum is String based. I need this in order to implement an NSValueTransformer.

Comment: "I need this in order to implement an NSValueTransformer" No, you don't. You are not going to be using any Swift enums in conjunction with an NSValueTransformer — not least because Cocoa, which is written in Objective-C, cannot even _see_ a Swift enum.

Comment: matt, as argued in my second comment from your answer, NSValueTransformer can in did not be used to transform Swift enums, however your reasoning is not entirely correct. Ojective-C can see Swift enums and the proof for it is that an UILabel (which is written in Objective-C) can actually see the NSLineBreakMode enum when it is used from swift. See the `lineBreakMode` property of `UILabel`.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's your enums, so you can't *not* know what type they are. Second, you're not going to receive an enum type, but an enum instance. Third, even if you insist on pretending not to know what type this enum is, it's easy to make a function that can be called only with an enum that has a raw value and check what type that raw value is:

```
enum E1 {
    case One
    case Two
}
enum E2 : String {
    case One
    case Two
}
enum E3 : Int {
    case One
    case Two
}

func f<T:RawRepresentable>(t:T) -> Bool {
    return T.RawValue.self == String.self
}

f(E3.One) // false
f(E2.One) // true
f(E1.One) // compile error
```

Comment: In my case "f(E1.One) // compile error" needs to compile and return false. Actually I need to find out whether a var of type AnyObject? is a string based enum.

Comment: Actually it looks like an enum in Swift is a value type (ie. Any not AnyObject) regardless of it's raw value. Unfortunately NSValueTransformer imposes a method signature with an argument of AnyObject and hence can not be used to transform Swift enums. I will be up-voting this answer because it actually checks the raw value type of the enum.

Comment: I don't think you're grasping the implications of my answer or the nature of the Swift language. No unknown enum types can ever arrive into your hands. Types in Swift are strictly determined at compile time.

Comment: Thanks matt. I think I am grasping the nature of Swift pretty well, and just to prove the opposite of what you wrote, "func test3(a: Any) {}" will actually loose the type of any enum that is passed to it. Admittedly, functions should not be written like this, and generics should be used. Also please bear in mind at one more often than not interacts with legacy code such as Objective-C code which still has interfaces that are based on the id type, and thus loses most of the type safety from Swift. In my case the variable type was imposed on me by the Objective-C API. See NSValueTransformer.

Comment: "In my case the variable type was imposed on me by the Objective-C API. See NSValueTransformer" Nothing about NSValueTransformer "imposes" an enum of unknown type such as you are artificially positing. If the problem is that you don't understand how to deal with NSValueTransformer in Swift, you should ask about that. I've answered the (very strange and probably irrelevant) question that you _did_ ask.

Comment: matt, you seem very keen to have the last word in this discussion, however, you must understand that in order to implement a NSValueTransformer one must override the `- (id)transformedValue:(id)value` method, which imposes the use of the type id. And I do understand how to use NSValueTransformer, however as I have argued in my second comment in this thread, Swift enums can not be transformed with it.

Comment: You don't have to "argue" that. It's just a fact. `id` = AnyObject = class. An enum is not a class.

Answer (score 1):

Generics to the rescue :

```
func enumRawType<T>(of v:T)-> Any? 
{ return nil }

func enumRawType<T:RawRepresentable>(of v:T)-> Any?
{ 
  return type(of:v.rawValue)
}


enumRawType(of:E1.One) // nil
enumRawType(of:E2.One) // String.Type
enumRawType(of:E3.One) // Int.Type
```